# How to make a ListView in Windows Phone 8.1 where i can put a handler in each item i choose

Tags: runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to create a ListView in XAML file by this example:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView1" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
<x:String>Item 1</x:String>
<x:String>Item 2</x:String>
</ListView>
```

But, how can I handle it if I click in Item 1 to go to other page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in your `ListView_SelectionChanged` method by checking `SelectedIndex` property of `listView1`. If the value will be 0, then you will know that the first item is selected, so you can perform navigation to another page.

Additionally, you should know that -1 means that no item is selected. It's a good practise to set the `SelectedItem` property of your `listView1` to null every time you navigate to the page with the list (`OnNavigatedTo()` method), because `SelectionChanged` event will not be fired when you click the item that is already selected.